# How to redirect a certain group login in to another page apex oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

so I'm kind of new to apex and If I had a log in page and a certain user logs in that belongs to a certain group... say customers? Well if they log in , it would redirect them to a customer application.. and this is what I'm currently trying to achieve but it doesn't work ):

This is my code, can you tell me why it doesn't work and a solution to it?

```
DECLARE
VAL BOOLEAN;
BEGIN 
IF
VAL := APEX_UTIL.CURRENT_USER_IN_GROUP(p_group_name=> 'Customer') 
RETURN TRUE
THEN

htp.init;
owa_util.redirect_url('f?p=&Custlogin.:1:&APP_SESSION.');
apex_application.stop_apex_engine;

END IF

END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IF statement isn't quite right; and RETURN is for stopping processing (and returning a value, if it's a function). I think you need something like this:

**Apex 4.1 or later**

```
BEGIN 
  IF APEX_UTIL.CURRENT_USER_IN_GROUP(p_group_name=> 'Customer') 
  THEN    
    htp.init;
    owa_util.redirect_url('f?p=&Custlogin.:1:&APP_SESSION.');
    apex_application.stop_apex_engine;    
  END IF;    
END;
```

**Apex 4.0 or earlier**

```
BEGIN 
  IF APEX_UTIL.CURRENT_USER_IN_GROUP(p_group_name=> 'Customer') 
  THEN    
    htp.init;
    owa_util.redirect_url('f?p=&Custlogin.:1:&APP_SESSION.');
    apex_application.g_unrecoverable_error:= true;    
  END IF;    
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey! Yeah I realised with the return and in the end separated the two statements to a PL for redirection and a boolean PL statement for validation!

But I should of checked sooner because your answer was a lot more condense to use :P Thanks for your reply!!!

Comment: No problem. If this answer helped you, you can click the "tick" to mark it as correct.

Comment: Which version of APEX does this apply to?